# AWS System Manager (SSM) get-command-invocation results in InvalidPluginName

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssm

I've been able to successfully send a SSM command to an EC2 instance.

Here is the Python Lambda code I'm using:

```
            # System Manager send_command
            response = ssm_client.send_command(
                        InstanceIds=[instanceID],
                        DocumentName=document,
                        Parameters={'action': ['Install'],'licenseKey': [licenseKeyValue],})
                        
            command_id = response['Command']['CommandId']
            print("Command ID: " + command_id)
```

The document is: arn:aws:ssm:us-east-2:539736333151:document/New-Relic_Infrastructure

[UPDATE: The issue is with a document having MULTIPLE plugins (action) which does this document does. Must use --plugin-name correctName to get status.]

I know the send_command is working with this document. I also know the commandID.

I've seen the results both on the instance as well as in the AWS CLI for Systems Manager -> Run Command interface.

Now, I'm trying to retrieve the commands status via get-command-invocation. My AWS CLI command:

```
aws ssm get-command-invocation --command-id 28XXXa35-dXX1-4XX1-9XX0-9ecfXXXX29ae --instance-id i-0c038XXXXc4e9c66e
```

I'm receiving this response:

> An error occurred (InvalidPluginName) when calling the
> GetCommandInvocation operation:

I've also tried:

```
aws ssm get-command-invocation --command-id 28XXXa35-dXX1-4XX1-9XX0-9ecfXXXX29ae --instance-id i-0c038XXXXc4e9c66e --plugin-name runShellScript
```

With the same exact response.

**Any thoughts on why I'm receiving an error for an invalid plugin *when it's optional*?**

From: aws ssm get-command-invocation help

> SYNOPSIS

> ```
>         get-command-invocation
>       --command-id <value>
>       --instance-id <value>
>       [--plugin-name <value>]
>       [--cli-input-json | --cli-input-yaml]
>       [--generate-cli-skeleton <value>]
>       [--cli-auto-prompt <value>]
> ```
>
> OPTIONS

> ```
>    --command-id (string)
>       (Required) The parent command ID of the invocation plugin.
>
>    --instance-id (string)
>       (Required) The ID of the managed instance targeted by the command. A
>       managed  instance  can  be  an Amazon EC2 instance or an instance in
>       your hybrid environment that is configured for Systems Manager.
>
>    --plugin-name (string)
>       (Optional) The name of  the  plugin  for  which  you  want  detailed
>       results.  If  the document contains only one plugin, the name can be
>       omitted and the details will be returned.
> ```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide actual command which you use?

Comment: For the command-id you need "The parent command ID of the invocation plugin."

Comment: @Marcin That is included above (minus the actual commandID and instanceID). I know both IDs are correct as I receive the commandID from my Python Lambda code and have confirmed it against the list of SSM run command. The instanceID has been confirmed from the running instance.

Comment: @HithamS.AlQadheeb I'm not sure what the 'parent command ID' is. I only know the commandID from the Python Lambda response using: command_id = response['Command']['CommandId']

Comment: Which run command are you executing? `AWS-RunShellScript`?

Comment: @Marcin I'm running an SSM Document. That document in turn will either run:       "action": "aws:runPowerShellScript",
...or:       "action": "aws:runShellScript",
Depending on OS.

Comment: You have to be more specific. I'm sorry, its not clear what are you doing. ` --command-id` is for run command id, not for ssm automation execution id. Can you provide an example of what are you  doing, where is execution id, where is run command id, with exemples of values?

Comment: @Marcin No worries at all - thank you for taking the time! I've updated the main post with more detail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

had the same problem with running `AWS-RunPatchBaseline`

If you look at the content of `New-Relic_Infrastructure` document you will notice that there are two actions that the document can run:
`aws:runPowerShellScript ("name": "WindowsInstallNewRelicInfrastructureAgent")` and `aws:runShellScript ("name": "LinuxInstallNewRelicInfrastructureAgent")`

so in order to get a result of ssm_client.get_command_invocation you will also have to send the `PluginName="WindowsInstallNewRelicInfrastructureAgent" or "LinuxInstallNewRelicInfrastructureAgent"`

The problem is that right after you call `ssm_client.send_command`, calling `get_command_invocation` will fail with the error

> An error occurred (InvalidPluginName) when calling the
> GetCommandInvocation operation

You have to wait till the command finishes running and you can check it by running

```
# we must wait for command to finish before we query the get_command_invocation on the instance, or else the Plugins list will be empty and we will crash
keepWaiting = None
while keepWaiting is None: 
    commandResp = ssm_client.list_commands(
        CommandId=command['Command']['CommandId'] #this way we will get only this command without it crashing because it is mising the Plugin name 
    )
    if commandResp['Commands'][0]['Status'] == "InProgress" or commandResp['Commands'][0]['Status'] == "Pending":            
        time.sleep(30)
    else:
        keepWaiting = 1
    )
```

Funny thing is that if you run in powershell:

```
Get-SSMCommandInvocation -CommandId 'theCommandIdYouJustGot' -Detail $true
```

you will see the command and it's status, and you can see that the `CommandPlugins` are empty while the status is `InProgress`, and when  status changes to `Success` the `CommandPlugins` will contain both values

Comment: Thank you for your help. This is the answer - I've run it in the aws cli: aws ssm... with the proper --plugin-name used.

I guess my issue is with the way the documentaiton is written: 

       --plugin-name (string)
          (Optional) The name of  the  plugin  for  which  you  want  detailed
          results.  If  the document contains only one plugin, the name can be
          omitted and the details will be returned.

Would have been nice if it has given information is your document contained more than one step and how to retrieve the overall status.

Comment: you are right. + the error message could give more details, though it says - the plugin name.. wasted a lot of time on this one